# Modifying Worksheet Template

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I found [this template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86467/163948) on TeX.SE (thank you to u/Qrrbrbirlbel), but wanted to know if someone could help me be able to add the ability to type  in the green solution box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[top=.5in, left=.5in, right=.5in, bottom=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\tikzset{
    all nodes/.style={
        rounded corners=6pt,
    },
    small node/.style={
        all nodes,
        inner sep=5pt,
        anchor=north west,
    },
    big node/.style={
        all nodes,
        align=center,
    },
    question/.style={
        big node,
        draw=red,
        fill=red!10,
        text width=.55\textwidth,
        inner sep=20pt,
    },
    question label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=red,
        fill=red!30,
    },
    hint/.style={
        big node,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!10,
        text width=.35\textwidth,
        inner sep=5pt,
    },
    hint label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!30,
    },
    answer/.style={
        big node,
        draw=green, 
        fill=green!10, 
    },
    answer label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=green,
        fill=green!30, 
    },
    reset/.style={
        rounded corners=0pt,
        minimum height=0pt,
        inner sep=.3333em,
        text width=,% reset
    }
}
\newlength{\nodeheighta}
\newlength{\nodeheightb}
\newcommand\WS[2]{%
  \sbox0{\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\node[question] (Question) {#1};}}%
  \sbox1{\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\node[hint] (Hint) {#2};}}%
  \setlength{\nodeheighta}{\ht0}%
  \setlength{\nodeheightb}{\ht1}%
  \ifdim\nodeheighta<\nodeheightb\nodeheighta=\nodeheightb\fi%
  \noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[question, minimum height=\nodeheighta,] (Question) {#1}; 
      \node[question label] at (Question.north west) {Question};
      \node[hint, minimum height=\nodeheighta, right=0pt of Question.north east, anchor=north west] (Hint) {#2};
      \node[hint label] at (Hint.north west) {Hint};

      \path let 
        \p2 = ($(Question.west)-(Hint.east)$),
        \n2 = {veclen(\p2)-\pgflinewidth},  % 0.4pt is the width of the border line
        \p3 = ($(Question.north)-(Question.south)$),
        \n3 = {\textheight-veclen(\p3)-10.4pt} 
        in node[
          answer,
          text height=\n3, 
          below=0pt of Question.south west,
          anchor=north west, 
          minimum width=\n2
        ] (Answer) {};
      % The Label
      \node[answer label, anchor=north west, inner sep=5pt] at (Answer.north west) {Answer};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

note: this is a headmatter file.  The usage is

```
\WS{Question}{Hint}
```

I want to get

```
\WS{Question}{Hint}{Solution}.
```

Also, I'd like the ability to add a title (header) / page number at the top.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why not post a link to the TeX.SE post? And it's usually better to add code directly to the post, instead of posting it on external sites?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've gone ahead and made the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Two different options are given below. I indicated by comments in the code where I added or changed things. In the first one only (at the moment at least) I add a page header with page number and a title given by a fourth argument to `\WS`, i.e. `\WS{Question}{Hint}{\lipsum[1]}{Title}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=.75in, left=.5in, right=.5in, bottom=.5in]{geometry} % increased top margin a bit
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{foo}{
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
 \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{foo}


\tikzset{
    all nodes/.style={
        rounded corners=6pt,
    },
    small node/.style={
        all nodes,
        inner sep=5pt,
        anchor=north west,
    },
    big node/.style={
        all nodes,
        align=center,
    },
    question/.style={
        big node,
        draw=red,
        fill=red!10,
        text width=.55\textwidth,
        inner sep=20pt,
    },
    question label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=red,
        fill=red!30,
    },
    hint/.style={
        big node,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!10,
        text width=.35\textwidth,
        inner sep=5pt,
    },
    hint label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!30,
    },
    answer/.style={
        big node,
        draw=green, 
        fill=green!10,
    },
    answer label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=green,
        fill=green!30, 
    },
    reset/.style={
        rounded corners=0pt,
        minimum height=0pt,
        inner sep=.3333em,
        text width=,% reset
    }
}
\newlength{\nodeheighta}
\newlength{\nodeheightb}
\newcommand\WS[4]{% <-- changed 2 to 4
  \sbox0{\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\node[question] (Question) {#1};}}%
  \sbox1{\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\node[hint] (Hint) {#2};}}%
  \setlength{\nodeheighta}{\ht0}%
  \setlength{\nodeheightb}{\ht1}%
  \ifdim\nodeheighta<\nodeheightb\nodeheighta=\nodeheightb\fi%
  \markright{#4}% <-- added
  \noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[question, minimum height=\nodeheighta,] (Question) {#1}; 
      \node[question label] at (Question.north west) {Question};
      \node[hint, minimum height=\nodeheighta, right=0pt of Question.north east, anchor=north west] (Hint) {#2};
      \node[hint label] at (Hint.north west) {Hint};

      \path let 
        \p2 = ($(Question.west)-(Hint.east)$),
        \n2 = {veclen(\p2)-\pgflinewidth},  % 0.4pt is the width of the border line
        \p3 = ($(Question.north)-(Question.south)$),
        \n3 = {\textheight-veclen(\p3)-10.4pt} 
        in node[
          answer,
          minimum height=\n3, % <-- changed to minimum height
          below=0pt of Question.south west,
          anchor=north west, 
          minimum width=\n2
        ] (Answer) {}; % <-- added #3
      % The Label
      \node[answer label, anchor=north west, inner sep=5pt] (AnswerLabel) at (Answer.north west) {Answer}; % added (Answerlabel)

      % added the following line
      \node[text width=0.95\textwidth, below right] at ([shift={(3mm,-3mm)}]AnswerLabel.south west) {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\WS{Question}{Hint}{\lipsum[1]}{Title}

\WS{Question2}{Hint2}{\lipsum[2]}{Title 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=.5in, left=.5in, right=.5in, bottom=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\tikzset{
    all nodes/.style={
        rounded corners=6pt,
    },
    small node/.style={
        all nodes,
        inner sep=5pt,
        anchor=north west,
    },
    big node/.style={
        all nodes,
        align=center,
    },
    question/.style={
        big node,
        draw=red,
        fill=red!10,
        text width=.55\textwidth,
        inner sep=20pt,
    },
    question label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=red,
        fill=red!30,
    },
    hint/.style={
        big node,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!10,
        text width=.35\textwidth,
        inner sep=5pt,
    },
    hint label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!30,
    },
    answer/.style={
        big node,
        align=left, % <-- added
        draw=green, 
        fill=green!10,
        text width=0.9\textwidth % <-- added
    },
    answer label/.style={
        small node,
        draw=green,
        fill=green!30, 
    },
    reset/.style={
        rounded corners=0pt,
        minimum height=0pt,
        inner sep=.3333em,
        text width=,% reset
    }
}
\newlength{\nodeheighta}
\newlength{\nodeheightb}
\newcommand\WS[3]{% <-- changed 2 to 3
  \sbox0{\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\node[question] (Question) {#1};}}%
  \sbox1{\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\node[hint] (Hint) {#2};}}%
  \setlength{\nodeheighta}{\ht0}%
  \setlength{\nodeheightb}{\ht1}%
  \ifdim\nodeheighta<\nodeheightb\nodeheighta=\nodeheightb\fi%
  \noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[question, minimum height=\nodeheighta,] (Question) {#1}; 
      \node[question label] at (Question.north west) {Question};
      \node[hint, minimum height=\nodeheighta, right=0pt of Question.north east, anchor=north west] (Hint) {#2};
      \node[hint label] at (Hint.north west) {Hint};

      \path let 
        \p2 = ($(Question.west)-(Hint.east)$),
        \n2 = {veclen(\p2)-\pgflinewidth},  % 0.4pt is the width of the border line
        \p3 = ($(Question.north)-(Question.south)$),
        \n3 = {\textheight-veclen(\p3)-10.4pt} 
        in node[
          answer,
          minimum height=\n3, % <-- changed to minimum height
          below=0pt of Question.south west,
          anchor=north west, 
          minimum width=\n2
        ] (Answer) {#3}; % <-- added #3
      % The Label
      \node[answer label, anchor=north west, inner sep=5pt] at (Answer.north west) {Answer};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\WS{Question}{Hint}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. Were you able to add a title area to it?

Comment: @MichaelLink Ah, sorry, didn't notice that part of the question. Are you talking about a standard page header?

Comment: @MichaelLink Also, should the title be unique to each page?

Answer (score 3):

This template can be easily done with a `raster` from `tcolorbox`. This way, all computings about size for nodes is autimatically solved by `tcolorbox` with option `raster equal height=rows` and a bottom box filling available space with `height fill`.

In this case I've also added a top row where an optional title and page number are included.

Now command `\WS` has on optional parameter (title) and three mandatory ones which are contents for `question` box, contents for `hint` box and contents for `answer` box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=.5in, left=.5in, right=.5in, bottom=.5in]{geometry}

\tcbset{
    mybox/.style={
        enhanced,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
        coltitle=black,
        colframe=#1,
        colback=#1!10,
        boxed title style={
            size=small,
            colback=#1!30},
        }
}

\newcommand{\WS}[4][Problem]{%
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster force size=false,
    raster equal height=rows,
    raster row skip=0pt,
    raster column skip=0pt,
    raster row 1/.style={
        mybox=orange,
        raster multicolumn=2,
        notitle},
    raster row 2 column 1/.style={%
        mybox= red,
        add to width= .05\textwidth,
        title=Question},
    raster row 2 column 2/.style={%
        mybox= blue,
        add to width= -.05\textwidth,
        title=Hint},
    raster row 3 column 1/.style={%
        mybox= green,
        raster multicolumn=2, 
        height fill,
        title=Answer},  
    ]
\tcbitem \textbf{#1}\hfill\thepage
\tcbitem #2 
\tcbitem #3
\tcbitem #4
\end{tcbitemize}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\WS{Suppose you have a right triangle as presented below.  Let $a=2$ cm, and $b=3$ cm.  How long would $c$ be? 
        {\par\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[rounded corners=0pt] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,3) -- (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \par}
        Remember to leave your answers as a square root, and to show all work and leave units.}%
{  \begin{itemize}
      \item Think about the pythagorean formula.
      \item It involves squares.
      \item And adding.
  \end{itemize}}{This is my answer

  \lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is great, quick question though, is it possible to make the `Solution` parameter _optional_?  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelLink what does it mean? If you leave it empty, nothing is written inside the green box.

Comment: @MichaelLink In any case, you wanted to write inside `solution` and Torbjørn T. provided a good answer to your question. `Solution` as a optional parameter completely changes the original question and makes our asnwers not so correct. I think you should open a new question.